# change barcolor Flyout xamarin xaml

Tags: xaml, xamarin

somebody knows how to change the bar color, that I point out in the image
[bar flyout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYxU7.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the background color of **Navigation Bar** in shell , we could set the style of Shell navigation bar in **Resource Dictionary** .

```
  <Shell.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Color x:Key="NavigationPrimary">#2196F3</Color>
            <Style x:Key="BaseStyle" TargetType="Element">
                <Setter Property="Shell.BackgroundColor" Value="Red" />  // set navigation bar color here
                <Setter Property="Shell.ForegroundColor" Value="Blue" />
                <Setter Property="Shell.TitleColor" Value="Blue" />
                <Setter Property="Shell.DisabledColor" Value="#B4FFFFFF" />
                <Setter Property="Shell.UnselectedColor" Value="#95FFFFFF" />
                <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarBackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource NavigationPrimary}" />
                <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarForegroundColor" Value="White"/>
                <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarUnselectedColor" Value="#95FFFFFF"/>
                <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarTitleColor" Value="White"/>
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="TabBar" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Shell.Resources>
```

Comment: i have the same, and it keeps looking blue  :  <Style x:Key="BaseStyle" TargetType="Element">
                <Setter Property="Shell.BackgroundColor" Value="Red" />
                <Setter Property="Shell.ForegroundColor" Value="White" />

Comment: Could you share your sample ? The above code works fine in my project .

Comment: it is too longer for 600 characters

Comment: You could create a new blank project with shell and test my solution .

Answer (score 0):

For NavigationPage (I assume your detail page is composed of a NavigationPage and inside your HomePage or CurrentNavigatedPageFromMenu, here is a simple style :

```
<Style x:Key="NavigationPageStyle" TargetType="NavigationPage">
    <Setter Property="BarBackgroundColor" Value="Red" />
    <Setter Property="BarTextColor" Value="White" />
</Style>

<Style BasedOn="{StaticResource NavigationPageStyle}" TargetType="NavigationPage" />
```

I separate them to allow to reuse the style on other Navigation page control I've extended.

In code behind, in the constructor of your page (can be usefull to provide a different color depend on the page you are, exemple : red for error page, green for parameter, blue for others).

```
((NavigationPage)Application.Current.MainPage).BarBackgroundColor = Color.Red;
((NavigationPage)Application.Current.MainPage).BarTextColor = Color.White;
```

You can find some usefull tips [Xamarin Forum too][1].